# is using a FAB for multiple user actions and screens good practice?

Tags: input, material-design, actions, floating-action-button

I'm working on a gaming product where users can perform a wide variety of actions from rating, writing a review, adding to lists, log the game in their 'backlog' etc..

Each of those can lead to multiple further screens with more user actions so i worry that using a FAB isn't relevant anymore.

Should a FAB be kept to single unique action (write a review, Log etc.. )? and if so what other alternatives could there be without cluttering too much?

[image: sample FAB results and user action]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen this answer to a related FAB question? https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/110434/97534. It looks to me like you might want a single FAB with a material sheet that slides out to give you the three options.

Comment: this actually helps indeed, Material sheet might be the way, thanks!